# 3e+3 = 3000 - JavaScript query

Tags: javascript

I was reading a JS book and there was a question asking for output of below:

```
3e+3
```

It is giving me `3000`. Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is called scientific notation, the `xey` means "`x` times `10` to the power of `y`"

In your case, `3 * Math.pow(10, 3); // 3000`

Answer (score 6):

`e` declares an exponent. This is known as exponential or [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

`3e+3` is equal to `3e3` (the `+` defines a positive number rather than addition), which is equal to `3 * (10^3)` which is equal to `3 * (10*10*10)` which is equal to 3000.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple scientific notation. `3e+3` is 3 times 10 to the 3rd power.